# How to resolve compiler error creating a SwiftData #Predicate?

Tags: swift, predicate, swift-data

I have been trying so many ways to resolve this issue. I am trying to fetch SwiftData records with a predicate. but everything I try results in a pair of errors:

> initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Item' conform to 'Encodable'

> initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Item' conform to 'Decodable'

The error is coming from within the expanded `#Predicate` macro.

Here is a bare bones class to demonstrate the issue:

```swift
@Model
final class Item {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var timestamp: Date

    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.id = UUID().uuidString
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}
```

And here is the bare bones code that causes the compiler issue:

```swift
extension Item {
    static func foo() {
        let item = Item(timestamp: .now)
        let pred = #Predicate<Item> { $0.id == item.id }
    }
}
```

I've tried so many ways to resolve this error. None of the Apple SwiftData sample projects I've seen give this error.

I've tried conforming to `Identifiable`. I've renamed the `id` property. I've changed the `id` type to `UUID` directly instead of `String`.

And of course I've added code to conform to `Codable`. While that fixed the compiler error, I ended up getting a runtime error. Note that none of the Apple SwiftData projects conform their models to `Codable`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is to avoid referencing a model object inside the `#Predicate` closure.

Simply change the predicate line from:

```
let pred = #Predicate<Item> { $0.id == item.id }
```

to:

```
let anID = item.id
let pred = #Predicate<Item> { $0.id == anID }
```

While the solution seems trivial and obvious, the error can easily lead you down many wrong paths.

Comment: To add to this, the #Predicate macro seems to currently be very sensitive to what code that can be added. I got the same error from unwrapping an optional in a `guard` statement, using the coalescing operator ?? instead I could turn it into a one liner and the code compiled.

Comment: Comparing to `nil` also seems to be problematic, so I had to make a dummy variable of the type I was comparing, set it to `nil`, and then compare on that.