# SwiftData @Query with #Predicate on Relationship Model

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

XCode 15 beta 6.

Just want to do a very simple Query Predicate where the relationship model matches:

```
@Query(
    filter: #Predicate<Piece> {
        $0.artist == selectedArtist
    },
    sort: [
        SortDescriptor(\Piece.age, order: .reverse)
    ]
) var pieces: [Piece]
```

and I'm receiving error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'PredicateExpressions.Equal<PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Variable, Artist>, PredicateExpressions.Value>' to closure result type 'any StandardPredicateExpression'

I also tried .id and .persistentModelId on the artist but no luck.

This seems like the most basic predicate use case so I'd be shocked if it's not supported. Any ideas what i'm missing?

My models are basic:

```
@Model
final class Piece {
    var age: Int
    var artist: Artist
}
```

And

```
@Model
final class Artist {
    var name: String
    
    @Relationship(
        deleteRule: .cascade, 
        inverse: \Piece.artist
    )
    var pieces: [Piece]?
}
```

Comment: I don’t think you have missed anything, this must be a bug. And you are [not alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77029083/how-do-i-filter-query-with-bound-item)

Comment: Can I ask what the use case is? I recently ran into a similar problem, but solved it by realising that I already had a reference to all the related `Piece` entries, on `Artist.pieces` so what's the need for a separate query?

In my case, my `Pieces` items were going to vastly outnumber my `Artist` items, so filtering every single Piece in order to find relevant ones was not the way to go.

I'd be curious to learn more about what you were trying to do?

Comment: You bring up a great point. I feel like I was overthinking this. I'm passing this view an "artist" so just displaying "artist.pieces" would have been enough, no need for #query at all. Maybe I thought sorting a lot of pieces at the DB level would be more performant than in array but at that point we're splitting hairs... I appreciate the comment.

Comment: That's great to hear. If it makes you feel any better, I went all the way down the rabbit hole on this too. In the end, the mistake I was making was I was inserting the new piece to the modelContext and then setting the relationship (`let newPiece = Piece()` → `modelContext.insert(newPiece)` → `piece.artists.append(artist)`) — _which were instructions I had found elsewhere_. INSTEAD the correct approach is somewhat counterintuitive: with SwiftData you can create the object and simply amend the parent and it works: (`let newPiece = Piece()` → `piece.artists.append(artist)`)

Comment: @RichardDas For me, the view will not redraw guaranteed when changes happen in the artists array. Manually appending like you described triggers a refresh, but using modelContext.delete(newPiece) would not in my case. Listening to the array via a query would solve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76632341/1807644), it seems like `#Predicate` will not let you use another `@Model` in the code block. Based on this logic, I don't think there's a way to do this as part of `@Query` without jumping through a bunch of hoops.

If your dataset is relatively small, the best suggestion is to filter it yourself:

```
@Query(
    sort: [
        SortDescriptor(\Piece.age, order: .reverse)
    ]
) var pieces: [Piece]

private var filteredPieces: [Piece] {
    return pieces.compactMap { piece in
        guard let artist = piece.artist else {
            return nil
        }
        return artist == selectedArtist ? piece : nil
    }
}
```

and you can use your filtered data below:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(filteredItems) { item in
            //show filtered stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

You gave me an idea and it worked !!!

Considering that you can't use another model in the predicate, then first set a variable with the persistentModelID and use that variable in the predicate.

I was having the same problem and this worked for me. Of course you need to set the query in your init()

EDIT: I added part of the code that could be helpful.

```
@Query private var homes: [Home]

init(session: Session) {
    
    let id = session.persistentModelID
    let predicate = #Predicate<Home> { home in
        home.session?.persistentModelID == id
    }
    
    _homes = Query(filter: predicate, sort: [SortDescriptor(\.timestamp)] )
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code snippets? This is a great suggestion. I didn't know it was possible to manipulate the query at run-time like this.

Comment: Done. I copied part of my code (names were modified to protect the innocents, lol)

Comment: This worked for me too. How come I have to capture `let id = session.persistentModelID` but when I just do `home.session?.persistentModelID == session.id` it does not work?