Extracting a view into a subview breaks onDelete of ForEach in SwiftUI
I have a SwiftData model Exercise which has an array of MySet, every MySet has an Exercise as a Parent
In the Main view I Query Exercise Model and Filter it:
@Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\Exercise.date, order: .reverse)]) private var exercises : [Exercise]
    
private var filteredExercises: [Exercise] {
    exercises.filter { $0.workout == workout }
}

Then in a List I have a Section where I iterate through these exercises:
Section(header: Text("Exercises")) {
    ForEach(filteredExercises){ exercise in
        VStack {
            Text("\(exercise.exerciseName.name)")
            SetsView(exercise: exercise)
            Button {
                if let exercisesets = exercise.sets {
                    if(exercisesets.count <= 7) {
                        let newSet = MySet(id: UUID(), weight: 0, reps: 0,isCompleted: false, exercise: exercise)
                        //ChatGpt I cannot see this being added until i Refresh the app
                        modelContext.insert(newSet)
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Add set")
                    .underline()
            }
        }
    }
    .onDelete(perform: delete)
}

The Delete method deletes using index:
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    let exercisesToDelete = filteredExercises
    for index in offsets {
        let exercise = exercisesToDelete[index]
        modelContext.delete(exercise)
    }
}

In the subview I simply Query the MySets:
@Query(sort: [SortDescriptor(\MySet.weight)]) private var sets : [MySet]

private var filteredSets: [MySet] {
    sets.filter { $0.exercise == exercise }
}

var body: some View {
    ForEach(filteredSets) { myset in
    //This Code works fine if i uncomment it
    HStack {
        Text("\(myset.weight)")
        Text("\(myset.reps)")
    }
}

Now when I introduce a new Subview the onDelete no longer works and crashes the app:
ForEach(filteredSets) { myset in
    // This Code works fine if i uncomment it
    // HStack {
    //     Text("\(myset.weight)")
    //     Text("\(myset.reps)")
    // }
                        
    // but this breaks the onDelete
    HStack {
        SetEditor(myset: myset)
    }
}

struct SetEditor: View {
    @Bindable var myset: MySet
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Weight")
            TextField(
                "\(myset.weight)",
                value: myset.weightBinding, formatter: NumberFormatter()
                )
        }
            
        VStack {
            Text("Reps")
            TextField(
                "\(myset.reps)",
                value: myset.repBinding, formatter: NumberFormatter()
               )
        }
    }
}

I can't figure out why adding the SetEditor view breaks the onDelete when it otherwise works fine and Xcode doesn't give me any meaningful error messages.

Your query is missing its predicate

Queries don't need predicates and since predicates don't support SwiftData relationships yet they aren't useful in this context

That is incorrect, you can use relationship properties in a predicate.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77039981/swiftdata-query-with-predicate-on-relationship-model

Yes like in Joel's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77251474/259521 You can also pass a computed Query into the View so don't need to write a custom init.

The problem is that I am deleting an Exercise while its Sets are still active in the UI. This crashes the app. So, before deleting the Exercise, delete all SwiftData objects associated with it:
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    let exercisesToDelete = filteredExercises
    for index in offsets {
        let exercise = exercisesToDelete[index]
        
        // Delete associated MySet objects first
        if let sets = exercise.sets {
            for set in sets {
                modelContext.delete(set)
            }
        }
            
        // Now delete the exercise itself
        modelContext.delete(exercise)
    }
}

